# How to force the serialization/deserialization of my custom type?

Tags: c#, serialization

Here is my code:

```
void Main()
{
    var test = new Order()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Title = "Test",
        Code = new Code("O-123456789") // TODO create a Code.NewCode() later
    };
    var line = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Code Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Code
{
    public string code;

    public Code(string code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

On the console I get this result:

```
{"Id":"227599fe-c834-4330-84e5-2018abe59e35","Code":{"code":"O-123456789"},"Title":"Test"}
```

But I want this:

```
{"Id":"227599fe-c834-4330-84e5-2018abe59e35","Code":"O-123456789","Title":"Test"}
```

So how can I force my Code type to serialize like I want. Actually, I want the same behavior of Guid(). Or find a way to implement String(). Could you help me on this.

I know I can probably use some attribute to force JSON serialization but I would like something that work for all serialization exactly like the Guid()

Comment: Json.Net converts the .Net Primitive of a Guid to a string (JSON Primitive) under the hood. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `JsonConverter` that deals with your type and then serializes it how you like:

```
public class CodeSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var code = value as Code;
        writer.WriteValue(code.code);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Code).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```

Once we have this you can plug it in to your `SerializeObject` method by setting some properties on `JsonSerializerSettings`:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsonSerializerSettings.Converters.Insert(0, new CodeSerializer());
var line = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, jsonSerializerSettings).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(line);
// {"Id":"2010e737-a9e8-4b77-bde6-1c50e92c6a30","Code":"O-123456789","Title":"Test"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it like this;

```
    public class Order
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public Code Code { get; set; }

        public string SerializedCode
        {
            get
            {
                if (Code != null)
                {
                    return Code.code;
                }
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

Output : {"Id":"227599fe-c834-4330-84e5-2018abe59e35","SerializedCode":"O-123456789","Title":"Test"}
```

Actually, you can't do it for all serialization actions. There is no generic way to perform it. Maybe you can provide own serializer class. But I think, it wouldn't be a good solution. You don't want serialized output and class object 
to be different from each other. It can be cause another problems.  I suggest you to change your class and properties to perform it.

Comment: Ok so how does it work for Guid() serialization and all type that are already in the framework?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe, the serializer determines the Guid type and converting it to string when serializing it.

Comment: JsonConvert.ToString(new Guid());

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the one given in comment by David Watts:

Json.Net converts the .Net Primitive of a Guid to a string (JSON Primitive) under the hood. All details on newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm

At a high level, the Json.NET serializer will convert primitive .NET values into primitive JSON values, will convert .NET arrays and collections to JSON arrays, and will convert everything else to JSON objects.

For other custom serialization I must use a JsonConverter as explained by Kevin Smith.